# Generate a list of dictionaries with all combinations from 3 dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of dictionaries of ALL combinations that are derived from 3 list of dictionaries combining their keys:

```
products = [{'product':'product1'},{'product':'product2'},{'product':'product3'},{'product':'product4'}]

sales = [{'sale':'sale1'},{'sale':'sale2'}]

invoices = [{'invoice':'invoice1'},{'invoice': 'invoice2'},{'invoice':'invoice3'}]
```

As a result i want all combinations of merging them:

```
combination_list = [
    {'product':'product1', 'sale':'sale1','invoice':'invoice1'},
    {'product':'product2', 'sale':'sale1','invoice':'invoice1'},
    {'product':'product3', 'sale':'sale1','invoice':'invoice1'},
    {'product':'product3', 'sale':'sale2','invoice':'invoice1'},
    {'product':'product3', 'sale':'sale3','invoice':'invoice1'},
.
.
.
.
    ]
```

I have read some info about itertools.product but have not manage to solve it.

Comment: do you have any key value pair which you want to match before merging them or you want to merge them anyways?

Comment: please provide the code you used. Using `itertools.product` sounds like a good idea

Comment: where did `'sale':'sale3'` come from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` with dictionary unpacking:

```
from itertools import product
products = [{'product':'product1'},{'product':'product2'},{'product':'product3'},{'product':'product4'}]
sales = [{'sale':'sale1'},{'sale':'sale2'}]
invoices = [{'invoice':'invoice1'},{'invoice': 'invoice2'},{'invoice':'invoice3'}]
result = [{**a, **b, **c} for a, b, c in product(products, sales, invoices)]
```

Output:

```
[{'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice1'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice2'}, {'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2', 'invoice': 'invoice3'}]
```

Edit: solution without unpacking:

```
result = [{'product':a['product'], 'sale':b['sale'], 'invoice':c['invoice']} for a, b, c in product(products, sales, invoices)]
```

More generic solution:

```
result = [dict(c for b in map(dict.items, i) for c in b) for i in product(products, sales, invoices)]
```

Comment: result = [{**a, **b, **c} for a, b, c in product(products, sales, invoices)]                                                                                                                        
                ^                                                                                                                                                                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax . I get this error on **a

Comment: @user1292656 That is because unpacking is only available in Python3. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: on this line result = [dict(c for b in map(dict.items, i) for c in b) for i in product(products, sales, invoices)] i get error: NameError: free variable 'dict' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Comment: @user1292656 You are probably assigning a value to `dict` somewhere in your code i.e `dict ={'something':'something'}`. `dict` is a builtin function and as such you should not shadow it by using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`collections.ChainMap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to the merge the cartesian products from [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from collections import ChainMap
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

products = [
    {"product": "product1"},
    {"product": "product2"},
    {"product": "product3"},
    {"product": "product4"},
]

sales = [{"sale": "sale1"}, {"sale": "sale2"}]

invoices = [{"invoice": "invoice1"}, {"invoice": "invoice2"}, {"invoice": "invoice3"}]

result = [dict(ChainMap(*x)) for x in product(products, sales, invoices)]

pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product1', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product2', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product3', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale1'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice1', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice2', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2'},
 {'invoice': 'invoice3', 'product': 'product4', 'sale': 'sale2'}]
```